# Adding a column which increment for every index which meets a criteria on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a column from a DataFrame to base my grouping on. I know that every NaN column under a non NaN one belong to the same group. So I wrote this loop (cf below) but I was wondering if there was a more pandas/pythonic way to write it with apply or a comprehension list.

```
import pandas

>>> DF = pandas.DataFrame([134, None, None, None, 129374, None, None, 12, None],
                      columns=['Val'])
>>> a = [0]
>>> for i in DF['Val']:
        if i > 1:
            a.append(a[-1] + 1)
        else:
            a.append(a[-1])
>>> a.pop(0)  # remove 1st 0 which does not correspond to any rows
>>> DF['Group'] = a
>>> DF
        Val  Group
0     134.0      1
1       NaN      1
2       NaN      1
3       NaN      1
4  129374.0      2
5       NaN      2
6       NaN      2
7      12.0      3
8       NaN      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) to identify non-NaN values. Then use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to create the `Group` column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([134, None, None, None, 129374, None, None, 12, None],
                  columns=['Val'])
df['Group'] = pd.notnull(df['Val']).cumsum()
print(df)
```

yields

```
        Val  Group
0     134.0      1
1       NaN      1
2       NaN      1
3       NaN      1
4  129374.0      2
5       NaN      2
6       NaN      2
7      12.0      3
8       NaN      3
```